# Add generated rows and columns to table in aspx file

Tags: asp.net, webforms, row, servercontrol

I want to add my table to the page, and the Table control is put in the aspx file and the columns and rows is generated in the aspx.cs file:

```
if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            var start = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
            var slut = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
            var diff = Int32.Parse(TextBox3.Text);

            for(int i = 0; i < (slut - start) / diff; i++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                tr.ID = "row" + i.ToString();
                for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
                {
                    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                    tc.ID = "cell" + j.ToString();

                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                }
                ??.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
```

And in aspx:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table" runat="server" Visible="true">

</asp:Table>
```

What should I write where the "??" is? ID doesn't work.

Comment: you should not really ask that question. you have the ID of a table and that's the object where you want to add rows

Comment: @SebastianSiek the OP had made a mistake of creating the ID the same as the class name and didn't understand that, thus the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the ID of your table to:

```
<asp:Table ID="MyTable" runat="server" Visible="true">
```

Then:

```
MyTable.Rows.Add(tr);
```

I think ASP.NET is getting confused because it has a control with the name `Table` and you tried to identify your table with `ID="Table"`.

Comment: i see what you did there Leniel, fixing your mistakes :P

Comment: @peroija: I did not understand your comment. What do you mean by your mistakes?

Comment: I was just joking with you because you originally had `Table.Rows.Add(tr)`

Comment: Is it possible to add a table with ID? I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Ah... OK. I got it! :) After posting that I realized the ID problem.

Comment: @HerrNilsson: Absolutely! It's the way the .aspx `Table` control is recognized inside the code-behind file. So the ID you place in your .aspx page is the identifier you'll use to access this server element in the code-behind file. What's the problem you're getting now? For further reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.aspx

Answer (score 2):

change your ID to Table1 or something else. `Table` is the name of a class which is probably why you are having a problem.